# how to use svgz file in html5 and jboss server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am using html5,jquery and jboss server for developing spring j2ee project.
I am using svg file in my website.this files are big size so i did compress svg to svgz type.
But i have problem for loading svgz file in browser.

my html code is:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" style="opacity: 0.6;" src="${context}/resources/svg/Valentines_Day_Heart_Card_Vector.svgz" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

The error is:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

how can i solve it?

Comment: what about using <object> instead of <embed> ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that the svg resource URL is available (that it's not a 404)
2. Check that it's sent with the correct mediatype, `image/svg+xml`
3. Check that it's served with a `Content-Encoding: gzip` HTTP header

You might want to consider using `Transfer-Encoding: gzip` instead, but that's up to you. See e.g https://stackapps.com/questions/916/why-content-encoding-gzip-rather-than-transfer-encoding-gzip.

Comment: I ended up using these techniques in a custom HTTP server with an SVG that was 377k uncompressed and 51k compressed.